# LINQ Query - Odd Result - OrderBy

Tags: sql, linq

I have the following code:

```
int pageNumber = 0;
int pageCount = 10;
int numberOfRecords = 10;

    var query = V_ers_notice.Skip(pageNumber * pageCount).Take(numberOfRecords );

return query.OrderByDescending(id => id.DOC_DATE).Select(ERSNoticeMap.DataToObject).ToList());
```

The ERSNoticeMap code is as follows:

```
public class ERSNoticeMap
{
        public static readonly Func<V_ers_notice, OGeneralFile> DataToObject = mapper =>
                                          new OGeneralFile
                                          {
                                              Docket = mapper.DOCKET,
                                              DocumentDate = mapper.DOC_DATE,
                                              FiledDate = mapper.FILED_DATE,
                                              FileGuid = mapper.FGUID,
                                              FileName = mapper.FName,
                                              FilePath = mapper.FPathName,
                                              FileSize = mapper.FSize,
                                              FileType = mapper.FType,
                                              Issuance = mapper.ISSUANCE,
                                              Title = mapper.TITLE,
                                              FileId = mapper.FID,
                                          };
}
```

And my OGeneralFile is as follows (even though it has nothing to do with this problem):

```
public class OGeneralFile
    {
        public int FileId { get; set; }
        public Guid FileGuid { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string FileType { get; set; }
        public string FileSize { get; set; }
        public string Issuance { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DocumentDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FiledDate { get; set; }
        public string Docket { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, here is the strange part. When I run this and look at SQL profiler, it is not ordering my query properly. I get the following:

```
SELECT [t1].[fID] AS [FID], [t1].[fGUID] AS [FGUID], [t1].[fPathName] AS [FPathName], [t1].[fName] AS [FName], [t1].[fType] AS [FType], [t1].[fSize] AS [FSize], [t1].[ISSUANCE], [t1].[DOC_DATE], [t1].[FILED_DATE], [t1].[DOCKET], [t1].[TITLE]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (10) [t0].[fID], [t0].[fGUID], [t0].[fPathName], [t0].[fName], [t0].[fType], [t0].[fSize], [t0].[ISSUANCE], [t0].[DOC_DATE], [t0].[FILED_DATE], [t0].[DOCKET], [t0].[TITLE]
    FROM [v_ers_notice] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t1]
ORDER BY [t1].[DOC_DATE] DESC
```

The order by should be in the inner query when selecting the top 10 not on the outside.

Any thoughts to why this may be happening?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your query is wrong. You need to `OrderBy` before you do skip and take, not after:

```
var query = V_ers_notice.OrderByDescending(id => id.DOC_DATE)
                        .Skip(pageNumber * pageCount)
                        .Take(numberOfRecords );
```

Comment: AH! I could have sworn I tried this combination.... Well, it worked!! Thanks for opening my eyes. +1 - Accepted.